# How can i read sensor output in the firebase realtime database and show it on a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, iot, nodemcu

I am doing an iot project using nodemcu esp8266 and an ultrasonic sensor. Then i upload the sensor output value to the firebase realtime database. but i don't know how to  read the sensor output value from firebase to the flutter android app .

I need the dart code for read the sensor output value from firebase to the flutter android app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To read data from the Firebase Realtime Database in your Flutter app, you can use the firebase_database package. Here's an example of how you can read the sensor output value from Firebase in your Flutter app:

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SensorDataPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SensorDataPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SensorDataPageState createState() => _SensorDataPageState();
}

class _SensorDataPageState extends State<SensorDataPage> {
  late DatabaseReference _sensorValueRef;
  double _sensorValue = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _sensorValueRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('sensor_value');
    _sensorValueRef.onValue.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        _sensorValue = event.snapshot.value ?? 0.0;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sensor Data'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Sensor value: $_sensorValue'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

try this..

Comment: an error occures

Comment: A value of type 'Object' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'double'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'double'.